# Modularização do schema usando AdonisJs e GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, adonisjs

Tenho um projeto onde estou usando AdonisJS e GraphQL, criei o schema e defini as *queries*, *mutations*, *types*. Porém tudo ficava centralizado em apenas um arquivo, então decidi modularizar o *schema* e os *resolvers*.

O problema é que quando vou exportar os arquivos que modularizei, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
typeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
at D:\Desenvolvimento\statsway\adonis-graphql-server\app\data\schema.js(anonymous):30
25    type Schema {
26      query: Query
27      mutation: Mutation
28    }
30  module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({
31    typeDefs: [
32      typeDefs,
33      Query,
34      Mutation,
35      userTypes
```

A dúvida é a seguinte: eu não posso fazer a concatenação dessa forma dentro do `module.exports`? Ou seria algum problema de `imports`?

Segue exemplo completo:

**UserSchema:**

```js
const userTypes = `
    # User definition type
    type User {
        id: Int!
        username: String!
        email: String!
        posts: [Post]
    }
`;

const userQueries = `
    allUsers: [User]
    fetchUser(id: Int!): User
`;

const userMutations = `
    login (email: String!, password: String!): String
    createUser (username: String!, email: String!, password: String!): User
`;

module.exports = {
  userTypes,
  userQueries,
  userMutations
}
```

**UserResolver:**

```js
'use strict'
const User = use('App/Models/User')

const userResolver = {
    Query: {
        async allUsers() {
          const users = await User.all()
          return users.toJSON()
        },
        async fetchUser(_, { id }) {
          const user = await User.find(id)
          return user.toJSON()
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        async login(_, { email, password }, { auth }) {
          const { token } = await auth.attempt(email, password)
          return token
        },

        async createUser(_, { username, email, password }) {
          return await User.create({ username, email, password })
        },
    },
    User: {
        async posts(userInJson) {
          const user = new User()
          user.newUp(userInJson)

          const posts = await user.posts().fetch()
          return posts.toJSON()
        }
    }
}
module.exports = userResolver;
```

**Mutation:**

```js
const { userMutations } = require('./user/userSchema');

const Mutation = `
    type Mutation {
        ${userMutations}
    }
`;

module.exports = Mutation
```

**Query:**

```js
const { userQueries } = require('./user/userSchema');

const Query = `
    type Query {
        ${userQueries}
    }
`;

module.exports = Query
```

E por fim o arquivo onde aparentemente o erro ocorre, **Schema**:

```js
'use strict'

const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')
const { Query } = require ('./query');
const { Mutation } = require('./mutation');
const { merge } = require ('lodash');

const { userTypes } = require ('./user/userSchema');
const { userResolver } = require ('./user/userResolver');

const resolvers = merge(
  userResolver
)
// Define our schema using the GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = `
  type Schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
  }
`
module.exports = makeExecutableSchema({ 
  typeDefs: [
    typeDefs,
    Query,
    Mutation,
    userTypes,
], resolvers })
```

Alguma sugestão do que pode ser o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu fiz uma pesquisa e parece que esse erro ocorre no pacote [`TypeScript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) entre as versões 2.4 e 2.7 (atualmente está na versão 3.2.1), quando "membros de uma classe são transformados com decoradores", veja aqui:

> - [Transforming class member with decorators throws · Issue #17384 · Microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17384)
> - [AOT build error Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined · Issue #8434 · angular/angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8434#issuecomment-357692603)
> - [ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined · Issue #10131 · angular/angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10131)
> - [TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined: ObjectLiteralShorthandRule · Issue #3525 · palantir/tslin](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3525#issuecomment-360802885)

Então tente alterar a versão do pacote TypeScript (no arquivo `package.json`) para uma versão mais recente (a 3.2.1 é a mais recente, mas não sei se o AdonisJS aceita essa versão, não consegui achar essa informação, o Angular por exemplo [não aceita](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8434#issuecomment-383712483)):

```
"typescript": "^3.2.1",
```

Depois disso [faça o seguinte](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8434#issuecomment-409764502):

- Exclua o arquivo `package_locked.json`;
- Exclua a pasta `node_modules`;
- Execute o comando `npm install`.

Comment: Realmente era o problema, ajudou bastante. Valeu.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu Diego! E qual versão do TypeScript você usou? (para deixar documentado caso alguém precise da solução também)

Comment: usei a 3.2.1 mesmo.